# (HTML) <img> Как вместо текста alt=»» показать изображение?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<img src="img/Grou.png" alt="dwz" >
```

Как вместо текста «dwz» показать другое изо ?

К примеру - «dwz.png»

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```html
<img alt="текст" src="изображение_не_существует.jpg" onerror="this.onerror = null; this.src = 'https://loremflickr.com/100/120'" width="100" height="120">
```

Comment: Все заработало Спасибо !